# Issues converting strings to numeric date formats R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, date-conversion

I want to convert a date column that has the following format `21 Septiembre 2019` into `21/09/2019` I have used `parse_date_time` but I keep getting an error.

**Code I a am using**

This is the object that contains the dates
`STM_silla_2$date`

`STM_silla_2$date <- parse_date_time(x=STM_silla_2$date,  orders = c("dBY", "dBy"))`
                                    ```

I get the following error. Could it be because the package does not recognize the months in Spanish?

`All formats failed to parse. No formats found`

**Here is some data sample**

`dput(STM_silla_2$date[1:5])`

`c(" 26  Septiembre  2016 ", " 06  Septiembre  2012 ", " 25  Octubre  2013 ",  " 07  Septiembre  2015"," 19  Noviembre  2014 ")`

I have also tried `dmy()` from `:lubridate` without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your locale to Spanish and then convert to `Date`

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","es_ES")
as.Date("21 Septiembre 2019", "%d %B %Y")
#[1] "2019-09-21"
```

After that `lubridate::dmy` would work as well

```
lubridate::dmy("21 Septiembre 2019")
#[1] "2019-09-21"
```

Comment: I got the following error `In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_ES") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "es_ES" cannot be honored`

Comment: @JoseDavid What's your OS ? It works for me on Mac.

Comment: My OS It is Windows

Comment: I don't have windows machine to test this but can you try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")`

Answer (score 3):

```html
library(readr) 
parse_date(" 26  Septiembre  2016 ","%d %B %Y",locale=locale("es"))
#[1] "2016-09-26"
```

add the Language code locale=locale("es")